# I can't send post request using Playwright

Tags: javascript, playwright, web-api-testing

I got this response:

---

Error: expect(received).toBeTruthy()

Received: false

---

This is my request:

````
test('should create a bug report', async ({request}) => {
    const response = await request.post('/v1/id/account', {
    data: { Account:
        {email_address: faker.internet.email(),
        password: faker.internet.password(),
        family_name: faker.name.lastName(),
        given_name: faker.name.firstName(),
        organization_name:faker.company.name(),
        phone_number: faker.phone.number('+32048#######')} }
});
    expect(response.ok()).toBeTruthy();
    const responseBody = JSON.parse(await response.text());
    console.log(responseBody);
    
})```
````

Comment: Have you tested api on postman ?

Comment: @Ashish Yes I have tested it and it works.

Comment: I feel the problem here might be with the request body you have attached. It would be great if you provide postman screenshot by hiding important details

Comment: @Ashish You can see the screenshot here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wuk37.png

Comment: So what is the response you're getting from Playwright?

Comment: @Ashish Just this 
Error: expect(received).toBeTruthy()

Received: false

Comment: have you tested my code @HamidHeravi

Comment: So debug it - check your API logs, see what the server responded with, try `console.log()` the response, etc ...

Comment: @HamidHeravi im waiting for you answer that my codes work for you or not ?

Comment: @Ashish I tested your code and it didn't work.

Comment: @oluroyleseyler sorry for the late response. Yes, I tested your code and it didn't work.

Comment: APIResponse: 405 Method Not Allowed
  Content-Type: text/html
  Transfer-Encoding: chunked
  Connection: close
  Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15724800; includeSubDomains
  CF-Cache-Status: DYNAMIC
  Report-To: {"endpoints":[{"url":"https:\/\/a.nel.cloudflare.com\/report\/v3?s=FM2dNVgva%2BNsE4rgY%2FyvcLfb5NEt9C%2FIGx0%2F7VW2V%2FPLVVfD9x%2B9VqnmKOzIgSwjPvzD8Q%2BBfpUKyQchcWULrISPVWvZHYbWCzXTITD5aJn5GK%2Bkn7TPPYMyZ84ikdPDENnpIOVHWbijcVbfzcCP0yH2"}],"group":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}
  NEL: {"success_fraction":0,"report_to":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}
  Server: cloudflare

Comment: @HamidHeravi change content type text/html to 'Content-Type': 'application/json' , that is why you are taking error , i edited for you my codes again , can you try again ?

Answer (score 1):

```
test('should create a bug report', async ({ request }) => {
  const email = faker.internet.email();
  const password = faker.internet.password();
  const familyName = faker.name.lastName();
  const givenName = faker.name.firstName();
  const organizationName = faker.company.name();
  const phoneNumber = faker.phone.phoneNumber('+32048#######');
  
  const response = await request.post('/v1/id/account', {
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    json: {
      Account: {
        email_address: email,
        password: password,
        family_name: familyName,
        given_name: givenName,
        organization_name: organizationName,
        phone_number: phoneNumber
      }
    }
  });
  
  expect(response.ok()).toBeTruthy();
  
  const responseBody = await response.json();
  console.log(responseBody);
});
```